# Python: how to monkey patch (swap) classes

Tags: python

Lets say I have the following 2 classes in module `a`

```
class Real(object):
    ...
    def print_stuff(self):
        print 'real'

class Fake(Real):
    def print_stff(self):
        print 'fake'
```

in module `b` it uses the `Real` class

```
from a import Real
Real().print_stuff()
```

How do I monkey patch so that when `b` imports `Real` it's actually swapped with `Fake`?

I was trying to do like this in initialize script but it doesn't work.

```
if env == 'dev':
    from a import Real, Fake
    Real = Fake
```

My purpose is to use the Fake class in development mode.

Comment: What is this initialize script it is another `.py` that runs at the start of your original program?

Comment: Yes it's a Django app, so the init script is in app.py, I didn't mention this for the purpose of being generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when you do -

```
from a import Real, Fake
```

You are basically importing those two classes into your `initialize` script's namespace and creating `Real` and `Fake` names in the `initialize` script's namespace. Then you make the name `Real` in `initialize` script point to `Fake` , but that does not change anything in the actual `a` module.

If `initialize` script is another `.py` module/script at runs at the start of your original program , then you can use the below -

```
if env == 'dev':
    import a
    a.Real = a.Fake
```

Please note, this would make `a.Real` to refer to the `Fake` class whenever you use `Real` from `a` module after the above line is executed.

---

Though I would suggest that a better way would be to do this in your `a` module itself, by making it possible to check the `env` in that module, as -

```
if <someothermodule>.env == 'dev':
    Real = Fake
```

---

As was asked in the comments -

> Doesn't import a also import into initialize script's namespace? What's the difference between importing modules and classes?

The thing is that when you import just the class using `from a import class` , what you actually do is create that variable, `class` in your module namespace (in the module that you import it to) , changing that variable to point to something new in that module namespace does not affect the original class in its original module-object, its only affected in the module in which its changed.

But when you do `import a`, you are just importing the module `a` (and while importing the module object also gets cached in the `sys.modules` dictionary, so any other imports to `a` from any other modules would get this cached version from `sys.modules` ) (Another note, is that `from a import something` also internally imports `a` and caches it in `sys.modules`, but lets not get into those details as I think that is not necessary here).

And then when you do `a.Real = <something>` , you are changing the `Real` attribute of `a` module object, which points to the class, to something else, this mutates the `a` module directly, hence the change is also reflected, when the module `a` gets imported from some other module.

Comment: If I do that inside `a` module, it would be buried inside module `a` and would be difficult for other people to realise what's going on, do you agree? Especially module `a` being a library.

Comment: Yea, possible if `a` is very very big, but I would say it would be harder for people to realize that its `init` module that is messing with `a` instead of the issue being in `a` itself. Lets say I am a new developer, I ran the code and see that I am getting some fake class when trying to call `Real` from `a` , I check inside the code in `a` and no where I find that `Real` is being overwritten by `Fake` , it would be very hard for me to guess/find out that `init` module is what is changing the `a.Real` to `a.Fake` . Do you agree?

Comment: I am quite noob on python imports, doesn't `import a` also import into `initialize` script's namespace? What's the difference between importing modules and classes?

Comment: Added a small explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `patch` from the `mock` module. Here is an example:

```
with patch('yourpackage.b.Real') as fake_real:
    fake_real.return_value = Fake()
    foo = b.someClass()
    foo.somemethod()
```

Comment: Doesn't your code only works within its with context? I am not not patching for unit test purpose in this case.